# RxSwift - order of emit on PublishSubject

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I know, that all types of Rx subjects can get elements in subscribe not ordered correctly, eg. if I send three elements in order 1,2,3, there is an option to get it on this order: 1,3,2.

I wonder, is there a way to force the order of emitted elements the same at the start and at the end?

Comment: Show some code so anyone who answers has a reference point to discuss names, methods, observables, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Only if you update it from different threads. Use *.serialize()* to ensure correct order.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct, that serialize() method could fix this, but it isn't implemented in RxSwift.

Comment: Indeed it isn't :( Perhaps *. concatElements()* from https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxSwiftExt will do the trick.